# C: code stops to work when I copy an array into another one

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make a code which creates all the permutations of some given numbers and then saves all of them into an array.
The permutation algorith works nicely, the problems arrive when I try to save every permutation into an array. The array is single-dimentional, so I wrote this code:

```
    m++;
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
        plist[m*len+i] = v[i];
    }
```

Where *m* is the number of times that the function is called (because it is recursive), *plist* is the array where I want to save all the permutations, and *v* is the single permutation array.

When I run this, the code stops to work without any error.

This is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int len;
int plist[100];
int m = -1;
void swap (int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void heappermute(int v[], int n) {
    int i;
    if (n == 1) {
        m++;
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
            plist[m*len+i] = v[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            heappermute(v, n-1);
            if (n % 2 == 1) {
                swap(&v[0], &v[n-1]);
        }
            else {
                swap(&v[i], &v[n-1]);
            }
    }
    }
}

int main()
{
   int num[11];
   int  i;
   printf("How many numbers you want to enter: ", len);
   scanf("%d", &len);
   printf("\nEnter %d numbers: ");
   for ( i = 0 ; i < len; i++)
       scanf("%d", &num[i]);
   heappermute(num, len);

   for (int i=0;i<96;i++){
    printf(plist[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? e.g. what is the value of `m*len+i` ? Is it still within the array?

Comment: I tried running it (ignoring all the compiler warnings) and I would not call `Segmentation fault` as "the code stops to work without any error."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int len;
int plist[100];
int m = -1;

void swap (int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void heappermute(int v[], int n) {
    int i;
    if (n == 1) {
        m++;
        for (i=0;i<len;i++){
            plist[m*len+i] = v[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            heappermute(v, n-1);
            if (n % 2 == 1) {
                swap(&v[0], &v[n-1]);
        }
            else {
                swap(&v[i], &v[n-1]);
            }
    }
    }
}

int main()
{
   int num[11];
   int  i;
   printf("How many numbers you want to enter: ");
   scanf(" %d", &len);
   printf("\nEnter %d numbers: ", len);
   for ( i = 0 ; i < len; i++)
       scanf("%d", &num[i]);
   heappermute(num, len);

   for (i=0;i<96;i++){
    printf("%d", plist[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

P.S. Instead of declaring plist to be of size 100 elements, you should dynamically allocate it to be of required size e.g for d digits, d * (number of permutations of d) elements

Comment: It actually works, but I can't spot the difference between mine and yours xD I checked it line per line but it seems to me exactly the same

Comment: The different line ... printf("How many numbers you want to enter: "); and printf("\nEnter %d numbers: ", len); The last one is printf("%d", plist[i]); you  never skip your compiler's warning...like note: expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'int'
   int __cdecl printf(const char * __restrict__ _Format,...);

Comment: @tommybee: Compiled with -Wall option of gcc, still no warnings on my machine.

Comment: @MatteoSecco: It it satisfies you, please accept the answer.

Comment: Oh ok, now it's clear, I was sure the problem was *plist[m*len+i] = v[i];* and I didn't checked the rest of the code. Thank you!

Comment: This might fix the compiler warning but does not fix that if `n` is greater than 4 then `plist[100]` is too small.